# Matlab Plot Smoothing having no effect

Tags: matlab, plot, smoothing

I'm currently having some trouble with the 'smooth' command, namely that it seems to have no effect on the generated plot. I have already used the following script to generate a plot

```
for h=1:4
    linespec = {'rx', 'gx', 'bx', 'yx'};
    hold on
    for b=1:365
        y=mean(mean(A(b,6*(h-1)+1:6*h)));
        p(h)=plot(b,y,linespec{h});
    end
    hold off
end
```

Going row by row in data set `A` and taking the average of the values in the first six columns, then column 7 through 12, 13 through 18 and 19 through 14; generating four plots in total.

The next step was to smooth the resultant plot by averaging the values over a span of 9. So, I tweaked the script to the following;

```
for h=1:4
    linespec = {'rx', 'gx', 'bx', 'yx'};
    hold on
    for b=1:365
        y=mean(mean(A(b,6*(h-1)+1:6*h)));
        w = smooth(y,9,'moving');
        p(h)=plot(b,w,linespec{h});
    end
    hold off
end
```

Essentially just adding the `w` variable and replacing `y` with `w` in the plot command. Yet this has no effect whatsoever on my plot. Matlab doesn't throw up any errors either, so there doesn't seem to be a problem with the input size. Does anyone have an idea as to what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

In either version of the loop, you appear to be plotting individual values of `y` against individual values of `b`. I presume, then, that `y` is a single value. You can't smooth a point, so the `smooth` operation is having no effect.

From the start, you don't need to make a loop to calculate the various means; `mean` can take a 2D matrix and return a vector. Calculate `y` in one go, then smooth that vector (should have length 365, I presume - depends on the size of input A). e.g.:

```
b = 1:365;
y=mean(A(:,6*(h-1)+1:6*h),2);
w = smooth(y,9,'moving');
plot(b,y,'rx');
hold on
plot(b,w,'gx');
```